# Is it possible to set a only specific region with google maps SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to show in my iOS app a only specific region, anyone knows if it's possible?
I want to disable the rest of maps regions.
I'm using iOS8 and Google Maps SDK version 1.9.1.

Tks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible however you may have a way, that you can try for yourself.

1. Zoom the map at some  level that no other region would display and then disable the map so no one can interact with it.
2. Add a view above the map, and now zoom the map at some level that unwanted region would go under that view and would not visible. Still you need to disable interaction for the map.